# iOS Facebook App link - open website if app not installed, open app otherwise

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

I have a website and am currently developing an iOS app.
I'm sharing the link to the website on Facebook. The URL scheme is working in the native app.

The HTML of the website starts like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myUrlScheme://myPath” />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="myAppAppleId" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="myAppName" />
    <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />

    <meta property="og:title" content=“myTitle” />
    <meta property="og:url" content="myUrl" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
</head>
```

When I open the app link from Facebook, it opens the native app if it is installed, otherwise it asks to go to the App Store, just like the documentation says.

If I remove "al:web:should_fallback=false", it will ALWAYS open the website in the browser, no matter if the native app is installed or not.

What I want is to open the website if the app is not installed, or open the app if it is installed. Is there any way I can achieve that ?

The iPhone is running iOS 9.3.5 and Facebook v63

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Even thou there is an "Open in .." option inside the embedded Facebook browser. But if you consider the AppLinks & deep links documentation, it should open the app if installed.